# upload file didn't work in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload a `.CSV` file to insert some records to my Database.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

My Routes:

```
Route::get('excel/import','Backend\ExcelController@getImport');
Route::post('excel/import','Backend\ExcelController@postImport');
```

My Controller:

```
public function getImport(){

    $csrf_field = csrf_field();
    $postUrl='import';
    $html = <<<CREATE
    <form action="$postUrl" method="post">
        $csrf_field
        <input type="file" name="importCsv" formenctype="multipart/form-data" ><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form> 
CREATE;
   return $html;
}


public function postImport(Request $request){
    //get file
    $file = Input::file('importCsv');
    dd($file);
   $upload=$request->file('importCsv');
   dd($upload);
}
```

It just print null if I use :

`Input::file('importCsv');<br>`

And nothing if I use :

`$request ->file('importCsv');<br><br>`

So, I've tried to print like `dd($request->all()); <br>`

```
array:2 [▼
"_token" => "wPuAXUvSItR4MFJ4bAjQhanaf0W9avrqR2PgjxcU"
"importCsv" => "T_OpusDef.csv"
]
```

I could get only the name, and when I want the the path by `getRealPath()`, It told me :

```
FatalErrorexception: call to a memeber function getRealPath() on null
```

I need your help, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form should look like this:

```
<form action="{{ $postUrl }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ $csrf_field }}
    <input type="file" name="importCsv"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, but your solution didn't work, I get the same result

Comment: @TengdaSu you shouldn't create HTML in the controller. Put all HTML to a Blade file and return the view from a controller method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Answer (score 1):

use **{{csrf_field()}}** instead of  **$csrf_field** if its in blade and **csrf_field()** if its in  controller